# how to install apt-get, raspbian

Tags: embedded-linux, raspbian, scratchbox

I am doing host target development within scratchbox. And apt-get is not installed in my target raspbian rootfile system.

What is the right apt-get package to use from here for raspbian ?
http://www.apt-get.org/main/

Should i use wget command for .deb package of apt-get ?
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-wget-your-ultimate-command-line-downloader.html
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/#more-1885

dpkg is installed in root filesystem of my target, i have checked it using whereis command

Please suggest, or can you suggest some link for installing apt-get itself. I am not able to find something related to it.

Any reply will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like maybe [debian apt package](http://wiki.debian.org/Apt) will get you there. I thought apt was just ubuntu but [no](http://www.apt-get.org/main/).

Comment: Joe:  http://wiki.debian.org/Apt  Don't forget that Ubuntu is based on Debian. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Raspbian FAQ is here: http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ

In it you can grab a list of apps included in Rasbian:

http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-armhf/Packages

You can grab the Raspbian package archive here:

http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-armhf/Packages.gz

Extract it, then use dpkg to install apt-get.

Comment: ---> now one question if i need ---  libstdc++6  --- for c++ library of raspbian which is based on armhf --- to compile c++ program -- then will apt-get able to install right library for raspbian armhf ? or i have to use dpkg to install library from the following link ------- http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-armhf/Packages.gz

Comment: but this link contains a file packages ? where is .deb file for the apt-get ?  --->>>>  http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-armhf/Packages.gz

Answer (score 0):

Install Putty.exe and login with putty to your raspbian with ip-adress of your raspbian and you can install apt-get!

Install the following:

```
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install gcc;
sudo apt-get install autoconf;
sudo apt-get install libtool;
sudo apt-get install pkg-config;
sudo apt-get install libselinux1-dev;
sudo apt-get install liblockdev1-dev;
sudo apt-get install gawk;
sudo apt-get install g++;
sudo apt-get install c++;
sudo apt-get install libgudev-1.0-dev;
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev;

mkdir -p $HOME/distr/libcec; 
wget -P $HOME/distr/libcec https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec/archive/master.zip;
unzip $HOME/distr/libcec/master.zip -d $HOME/distr/libcec/;
cd $HOME/distr/libcec/libcec-master ./bootstrap;"
./configure --with-rpi-include-path=/opt/vc/include --with-rpi-lib-path=/opt/vc/lib --enable-rpi;
make;
sudo make install;
sudo apt-get install cec-utils;

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo rpi-update
sudo reboot
```

After the reboot, is everything up-to-date and you have no problems anymore!